# In a document two key values should not have same value

Tags: mongodb

i am designing a database for storing chat history of a user in which sender and receiver can't be same person.so document should be like this 
`{sender :1 ,receiver:2}` but if a user insert a document `{sender :1,receiver :1}` then it should give an error.How to acheive this on javascript console.please guideline.i am designing database in mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of constraint should be checked in your application code before you save each message.  In the shell, you could have a function such as this that checks if a message is valid before saving it into the database.

```js
function sendMessage(message) {
  if(message.sender == message.receiver) {
    throw "Cannot send message to self";
  } else {
    db.messages.save(message);
  }
}
```

You might also consider encoding the `[sender, receiver]` relationship as a two-element list in the message object, where order defines which user is the sender and which is the receiver. This would allow you to easily search for all messages involving a given user.

For example, if a Message object is of the form `{ senderReceiver: [1, 2] }`,
then you could find all messages involving user 2 with the query `db.messages.find({senderReceiver: 2})`.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a check point,`msgHistory{sender:1,receiver:1}` is the object, check if both sending and receiving are equal by `if(msgHistory.sender == msgHistory.receiver){ // Do nothing } else {//Do something }` ... if you ask me `sender` and `receiver` should be assigned with Boolean, it makes efficient.